# Rails 3 - how to apply link_to on image_tag with :remote => true attrubute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, image, view, link-to

I am struggling with problem about right setting parameters for image, that is link. Concrete,

## this works

```
<%= link_to (image_tag 'img name', 
            :class => 'css'),
        ({controller, action, parameter})%>
```

## this already not works

```
<%= link_to (image_tag 'img name', 
            :class => 'css'),
        ({controller, action, parameter},
        {:remote => true})
%>
```

May you will think it's very low question, but I am trying to solve it more than half hour and still nothing... so I will appreciate for each of help.

Comment: Try this   link_to image_tag 'img name', 
            :class => 'css',
        {controller, action, parameter},
        {:remote => true}

Comment: what error did you get ?

Comment: just bad syntax, problem with brackets. The answer below solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. (not tested myself)

`<%= link_to(image_tag('img name', :class => 'css'), url_for(:controller => 'controller_name', :action => 'action_name'), :remote => true) %>`